# How do I pass a javascript variable to php and reload a frame

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

Ok this may sound a little weird but what i have is a frameset generated by php with codeigniter framework.

In one frame i am displaying rows of database query results with links attached to the row index of each record.

What I want to happen, is that you click one of the links and it brings up a more detailed summary of the record in the right hand frame.

While I am aware of the fact that php is server side etc. i was trying to make the link reload the right hand frame with the value of the index from the left hand side, then within the controller i can query the database using the index and push back the same summary page with the full record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send an AJAX request to the server with the variable. You can google on How to send ajax request to server.

However, Here is a simple example of this, using jQuery

```
$.post("/next/page", {
   'variable1' : 'value1'
}, function(data) {
   //on success handler
});
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback guys. Ended up using Starx's solution with a bit of tweaking. Thank you all.

Comment: @bisslad, Make sure you accept this answer if the solution worked. Click on (tick) on the left of the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want the link definition in the left frame to be something like this:

```
<a target="otherframe" href="otherframeurl.php?index=2">item 2</a>
```

Where otherframe is the title of the right frame.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your frames have names. Assuming the right frame's name is "right", you can change its href with JavaScript like this (from another frame):

```
parent.right.location.href = 'somefile.php?param=' + yourJsVariableHere;
```